# Unable to get GridView1_RowCommand to fire

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a hyperlink column on my gridview and the text is "View" I would like it so that when "View" is clicked on whatever row, it takes that rows ID which is in the next column and then redirects to the next form. It is redirecting fine, but it is not assigning the session to anything because GridView1_RowCommand not firing? I also tried GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged and that doesnt fire either. Any suggestions?

```
 Private Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    Session("ReferenceNumber") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add the ASPX markup for your GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fire the RowCommand event, you need to set the CommandName property of the button / link being clicked.  From the [RowCommand event documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx):

> To perform one of these operations, set the CommandName property of a
>   button to one of the values in the following table.

I would recommend using a [CommandField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx) (rather than a hyperlink field) to do this, and set the "ShowSelectButton" property to true.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true"
            SelectText="Select"
            headertext="Select Controls"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be working but now I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of object for    Session("ReferenceNumber") = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(0).Text

Comment: @user1342164 Right. You probably want to put that code in the SelectedIndexChanged event, actually. Rather than in the RowCommand event.  It's possible that the SelectedRow hasn't populated yet.  Also, in your question, you used an index of "1", and in the comment you used an index of "0".  So maybe it's just a typo?